# BMX pedal thread pitch

Tags: pedals, bmx

I found a bmx in the garbage and fixed it up but when went to replace the pedals bought the wrong size. I'm wondering if someone can help me out. I was testing the old thread in my socket set an it screws into a 15/32 inch socket.

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't try to screw the left pedal into the right crank and vice-versa?

Answer (score 1):

Most pedal threads are 9/16" with the left pedal being left-hand thread (ie backwards to normal)   Kids bikes might have 1/2" axles or 9/16"

There were some crazy metric threads used in the 80s but they were very rare and never took off.

Not sure how you got it to work into a 15/32" other than that's vaguely close to 1/2" suggesting a kid's BMX.

Answer (score 1):

Most (all?) bicycles with one-piece cranks accept "standard" 1/2" pedals. The thread is 1/2-20, with the left pedal being left-hand threaded. The wrench size and type varies depending on the pedal. Many cheap or old-school BMX bikes have one-piece cranks.